# Starting a jms Connection with standalone MQ Clientdriver

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I want to check if a JMS-Connection to a remote queuing is working. As this should be kind of J-Unit Test I can't use a Server (in my case would be Websphere. Is there any driver implementation or API I could use to initialize the connection ?

Answer (score 1):

No; without a backend Queuemanager there's nothing to respond to the connection. Messaging is inherently a distributed / networked product. There isn't something like a 'mock' QueueManager. In order for the connection to be properly created the mock would need to implement a lot of real function.